# Using key Performance indicator on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, kpi

I have a list, how do i add kpi indicator on the list. Since I have a column on that list as Project health. If I add green on project health i want to display green round, if yellow then yellow triangle, if red then red hexagon. Can anyone please help me.
Thanks
Mohammed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a calculated column to show KPIs on same list.

**Note:-**

1. I have used below formula to check for 3 conditions like Green, Red & Yellow.
2. I used column named budget with dropdown to select one of the value given above.
3. I have uploaded all the images in **SiteCollectionImages** library.

Please check below formula

```
=IF(Budget="Green","<img title='Green' border='0' alt='Green' src='http://myspsite/sites/ITPMO/SiteCollectionImages/StatusIcons/Green.png'>",
IF(Budget="Yellow","<img title='Yellow' border='0' alt='Yellow' src='http://myspsite/sites/ITPMO/SiteCollectionImages/StatusIcons/Yellow.png'>",
IF(Budget="Red","<img title='Red' border='0' alt='Red' src='http://myspsite/sites/ITPMO/SiteCollectionImages/StatusIcons/Red.png'>","")))
```

Please let me know if any query.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41731/discussion-on-answer-by-hardik-using-key-performance-indicator-on-sharepoint-201).